# modify weka source code in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7, weka

i wanna use weka source code (not jar file!)and i download weka-src.jar from this address
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/w/Downloadwekadev379sourcesjar.htm
and i wanna have weka project in netbeanes in windows .i do step by step this site instruction 
http://weka.wikispaces.com/Netbeans+6.0+%28weka-src.jar%29

when i extract jar file into src directory in my project,it give me a lot of error
such as:
package java_cup.runtime does not exist
and a lot of other error.

anyone can tell me how can i do that without any error ?? i am working on this problem for a week and i'm so tired.
please help me if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to download **java-cup.jar** file And add this jar to your **classpath**

if you didn't find **java-cup.jar** then you can download **jflex.jar** jflex also contain java-cup classes so you can download **jflex.jar** from link below

[click on this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/JFlex/JFlex.jar.zip)