# WEKA source code is compiling with errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, weka

I am trying to modify WEKA source code.
I tried the link on [modify weka source code in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738659/modify-weka-source-code-in-netbeans) but is no longer working. I am trying to run the WEKA java source code in Intellij and I get 100 errors (literally) coming from the weka, like

```
Error:(23, 44) java: package com.googlecode.jfilechooserbookmarks does not exist
Error:(28, 1) java: package no.uib.cipr.matrix does not exist
```

and it goes on. 
I tried to import it as a Maven project because of the pom.xml dependencies. It compiles and builds without any problem, but when I try to run a Java class, ex. Main.java, it gives all the errors above.

My project structure is:

```
Project
-scr
--main
---java (Source Folder)
----Main.java

-weka-src
--src
---main
----java (Source Folder)
------weka
```

Does anyone have an idea of how it can compile without errors? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks likeyou miss jars in your classpath which contains the packages `com.googlecode.jfilechooserbookmarks` and `no.uib.cipr.matrix`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jens for the comment!

Indeed, there were some dependencies I needed to add to pom.xml. Now it's working. This is what I added:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.jfilechooser-bookmarks</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfilechooser-bookmarks</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.vbmacher/java-cup-runtime -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.vbmacher</groupId>
          <artifactId>java-cup-runtime</artifactId>
          <version>11b</version>
      </dependency>
```